# Javascript, Jquery append functions to an event

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is associated with an event, say onfocus() and in some cases, I want to be able to execute the default function as well as one or more additional functions.

So I don't want to replace the original function, but I want to append another so that both functions will fire.

```
<div id="mydiv" onfocus="alert('hello');">
if(something == somethingelse) $('#mydiv').onFocus += "alert('world');"
```

So in this example, sometimes just Hello will Fire and sometimes Hello and then World will both fire.

I'm just using onfocus() and alert() as an example, these would actually be functions that I have defined.

How do I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to add a focus event handler

```
<script>
    $('#mydiv').on('focus', function(){
        //do soemthing
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with jQuery don't use inline event bindings, use the following instead:

```
$("#mydiv").on("focus", function() {
    alert("hello");
});

// add one more action for the same event
$("#mydiv").on("focus", function() {
    alert("world");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('#myDiv').on('focus', function(){alert('world')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mydiv').focus( function(){
})//This is for the elements which load while the page is loading
```

or

```
$('#mydiv').on('focus', function(){ 

 })  //This is for the elements which will load dynamically after the page load completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery try this, its an pure javascript equivalent:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").addEventListener("focus", function() { alert('world'); });
```

and if you want it to be compatible with IE8 and older you should try

```
var el = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if(el.addEventListener)
    el.addEventListener("focus", function() { alert('world'); });
else
    el.attachEvent("focus", function() { alert('world'); });
```

Comment: Need to test of IE support

Comment: Internet Explorer versions prior to IE 9, you have to use `attachEvent` rather than the standard `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery, you want to use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to bind event handlers to elements as opposed to specifying them inline

```
$('#mydiv').on('focus', function () {
    alert('hello');
});

$('#mydiv').on('focus', function () {
    if (something === somethingelse) {
        alert('world');
    }
});
```

or combining into one handler function seems reasonable in this case

```
$('#mydiv').on('focus', function () {
    alert('hello');

    if (something === somethingelse) {
        alert('world');
    }
});
```

When specifying them inline as you have done, only one event handler can be bound to the event so if you want to bind multiple event handlers, you either need to *bend* the one event handler limitation to handle this or use another approach, such as [DOM Level 2 events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) or an abstraction on top of it (such as jQuery's `on()` function).

Event handlers need to be bound when the element to which you are binding the handlers exists in the DOM. To do this, you can use jQuery's **[`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** function

```
// bind an event handler to the "ready" event on the document
$(document).ready(function () { 
    // ..... here 
});
```

or shorthand

```
$(function () { 
    // ..... here 
});
```